What's the best way to research personal military records of a soldier that served in the 101st Airborne Division during WWII?
I'm trying to conduct research on an soldier that served in Company B, 327th Glider Infantry Regiment, 101ST Airborne Division in WWII.  I have his name and birthday but no additional identifying information.  His name was PVT George A. Barkley, from Ohio and his birthday was 28 FEB 1920. He served in Operation Market Garden. Any help or advice on how to research this gentlemen's military service would be very welcome! I'm an amateur researcher and appreciate any help!

If you google 'US military records', various sites come up but it seems you need to sign up for a free trial for most of them. However, this US  govt. site might be a good starting point: National Archives Military Records

You could also try nosing around here, maybe posting a question somewhere, http://327th-gir.com/index.php/history-of-the-327th.  Also I've found that some of the folks here are pretty good at sleuthing for information . . . you'll have to set up an account. https://www.usmilitariaforum.com/forums/
